# sum up a column in a datatable against an other column in same Datatable

Tags: vb.net

i have a Datatable having following result from database

```
ID  Name           Class    FeeName       Amount
9   gumman hgjgh    6Th      Fine            0
9   gumman hgjgh    6Th   Tution Fee       3000
9   gumman hgjgh    6Th   Lebority Fee     500
10  AAdil Hussain   5Th     Fine             0
10  AAdil Hussain   5Th   Tution Fee       3000
10  AAdil Hussain   5Th   Lebority Fee      500
```

i want to sum up amount against each ID so i implement following code

```
Dim TotalAmount As New DataColumn("TotalAmount", GetType(Double), "Sum(Amount)")
Dtable.Columns.Add(TotalAmount)
```

But result is following

```
ID  Name           Class    FeeName       Amount      TotalAmount
9   gumman hgjgh    6Th      Fine            0           7000
9   gumman hgjgh    6Th   Tution Fee       3000          7000
9   gumman hgjgh    6Th   Lebority Fee     500           7000
10  AAdil Hussain   5Th     Fine             0           7000
10  AAdil Hussain   5Th   Tution Fee       3000          7000
10  AAdil Hussain   5Th   Lebority Fee      500          7000
```

but i want to sum up amount against each Name or ID
i have not idea of LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid a `DataTable's` [Column-Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) cannot `SUM(Amount)OVER(PARTITION BY ID)`.

Here's the LINQ solution:

```
Dim idGroupAmounts =
    From row In DTable
    Group row By ID = row.Field(Of Int32)("ID") Into IDRowGroup = Group
    Select New With {
        .ID = ID,
        .IDRows = IDRowGroup,
        .IdSum = IDRowGroup.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Double)("Amount"))
    }
For Each idGrpAmount In idGroupAmounts
    Dim id = idGrpAmount.ID
    Dim totalAmount = idGrpAmount.IdSum
    Dim rows = idGrpAmount.IDRows
Next
```

Comment: thank for help. i used `SUM(Amount)OVER(PARTITION BY ID)` in sql query from where i want to get the result so i found my desired Output.